# Removing unused data in Docker

Tags: docker

I have these commands defined in a Makefile for removing unused Docker data:

```
docker image prune -f
docker container prune -f
docker network prune -f
```

I've noticed that there's also `docker system prune`.

```
prune       Remove unused data
```

Is it equivalent to running the above three commands?

Comment: The [`docker system prune`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/) documentation seems like it answers this.

Comment: I don't see any mention that that's the same as running all of `docker * prune` separately.

Answer (score 1):

```
docker system prune

WARNING! This will remove:
        - all stopped containers
        - all networks not used by at least one container
        - all dangling images
        - all build cache
```

So yes it is equivalent, but you can add `--volumes` since it is not default.